# WSL terminal picks up command but integrated VSCode intergrated terminal doesn't

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

From the WSL:

```
ignoring_gravity@ignoring-gravity02:~/test-repo$ pwd
/home/ignoring_gravity/test
ignoring_gravity@ignoring-gravity02:~/test-repo$ virtualenv --version
virtualenv 20.1.0 from /home/ignoring_gravity/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py
```

From the VSCode integrated terminal:

```
ignoring_gravity@ignoring-gravity02:~/test-repo$ pwd
/home/ignoring_gravity/test-repo
ignoring_gravity@ignoring-gravity02:~/test-repo$ virtualenv --version

Command 'virtualenv' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install virtualenv
```

Any ideas why the vscode intergrated terminal doesn't pick up a command which is picked up by the WSL terminal?

---

output of `echo $PATH`:

WSL:

```
/home/ignoring_gravity/.poetry/bin:/home/ignoring_gravity/.local/bin:/home/ignoring_gravity/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2020.812.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/mnt/c/Users/ignoring.gravity.CORP/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/ignoring.gravity.CORP/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/ignoring.gravity.CORP/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Miniconda3:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Miniconda3/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/ignoring.gravity.CORP/AppData/Local/Pandoc/:/mnt/c/Users/ignoring.gravity.CORP/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/:/snap/bin
```

VSCode:

```
/home/ignoring_gravity/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/mnt/c/Users/ignoring.gravity.CORP/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/ignoring.gravity.CORP/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/ignoring.gravity.CORP/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Miniconda3:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Miniconda3/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/ignoring.gravity.CORP/AppData/Local/Pandoc/:/mnt/c/Users/ignoring.gravity.CORP/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/
```

Comment: can you run `echo $PATH` in both of them and add the results?

Comment: @RonSerruya sure, done

Comment: looks like you are using different Python interpreters, and miniconda does not have `virtualenv` installed. What interpreter have you selected in the config of VSCode?

Comment: Looks like poetry isn't in your vscode path. Do you know which `rc` files are being loaded? Try exporting `/home/ignoring_gravity/.poetry/bin` to your `.bashrc`?

Comment: I don't have any Python Interpreter set in my `settings.json` files...maybe VSCode is selecting the miniconda one by default?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity  -I can get its version number and path in the terminal. And it is recommended that you use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new terminal or reload VSCode.

Comment: @JillCheng yes, I use Ctrl+Shift+` - doesn't seem to make a difference though

Comment: @ignoring_gravity -Please check whether the selected Python interpreter in VSCode is available and try to reinstall the Python extension.